# understand BIND9, DNS Master and Slave Zones

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, dns-zone, master-slave

edit: (for clarification)

I have two servers. Server 1 has a static IP, and server2 has a dynamic hostname using DDNS services. both servers are running Ubuntu 12.04 lts, and virtualmin.

on server 1, we are running bind9, and and it has a Master Zone for its official domain, lets call it MyWebsite.com

server two (2), can be accessed via server2.mywebsite.com. we have already created a CNAME record, which points to its hostname provided by DDNS services

our problem is understanding how to get **server 2** to a add a simple CNAME record to the primary machine's Master Zone file for the domain.

all we need to do is add a record similar to this:

user1.mywebsite.com -> CNAME -> server2.mywebsite.com

to the Master Zone file for the domain ***On the primary server***.

(this is already working in practice. we need a way to have the template automatically add a CNAME record to the primary machines bind9 master zone file setup upon creation. at this moment, we are **doing it by hand**)

Thank you!

Comment: "even if it just adds ONE cname.." What is "it"? The server hardware can't do it, so what software are you talking about? And you can't point a CNAME to an IP Address, otherwise it would be an A record, so share some more information with us so we can give you better answers without taking stabs in the dark.

Comment: the idea would be for SERVER 2 to add a cname record to SERVER1 under the master zone. simply needs to add user.mywebsite.com -> server2.mywebsite.com. my problem is that i am having trouble figuring out how to add a CNAME records to the master zone on server 1.

Comment: i edited my question for clarification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd look into using [nsupdate](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/591).

You could run it on server2 out of cron.

> > update add www1.example.com 86400 a 172.16.1.1
> >
> > update add www.example.com 600 cname www1.example.com.
> >
> > send
> >
> > update add 1.1.16.172.in-addr.arpa 86400 ptr www1.example.com.
> >
> > send

Note, however, that chaining CNAMES is discouraged.  See, eg, [RFC 1034](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1034.html).

Comment: while this wasn't exactly what i needed to fix my problem, it may be of critical use in the future, and was one of many posts which help me gain a greater general understanding in parts of the DNS protocol which i had not before: answer selected